# Why is my solidity compiler not generating bytecodes?

Tags: solidity-0.8.x

For some reason the my solidity compiler did not include many fields in the contract.json file. Most importantly I miss the data field. The first field I get is abi.

Here is my contract:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.9;
import "./HederaTokenService.sol";
import "./IHederaTokenService.sol";
import './MintAssociateTransferHTS.sol';
contract Crowdsale {
  

bool public icoCompleted;
   uint256 public icoStartTime;
   uint256 public icoEndTime;
   int64 public tokenRate;
   address public tokenAddress;
   uint256 public fundingGoal;
    address payable public owner;
    MintAssoTransHTS public tokenService;
   modifier whenIcoCompleted {
      require(icoCompleted);
      _;
   
   }
    modifier onlyOwner {
      require(msg.sender == owner);
      _;
   }
   constructor(uint256 _icoStart, uint256 _icoEnd, int64 _tokenRate, address _tokenAddress, uint256 _fundingGoal)  {
   require(_icoStart != 0 &&
      _icoEnd != 0 &&
      _icoStart < _icoEnd &&
      _tokenRate != 0 &&
      _tokenAddress != address(0) &&
      _fundingGoal != 0);
   icoStartTime = _icoStart;
   icoEndTime = _icoEnd;
   tokenRate = _tokenRate;
   tokenAddress = _tokenAddress;
   fundingGoal = _fundingGoal;
   owner = payable(msg.sender);
   tokenService=new MintAssoTransHTS(tokenAddress);
   }

  
   fallback () external payable {
      buy();
   }
   function buy() public payable {
    int64 tokensToBuy;
    tokensToBuy = int64(uint64(msg.value))*tokenRate;
    tokenService.tokenTransfer(msg.sender,msg.sender,tokensToBuy);
   }
    receive() external payable whenIcoCompleted {
         owner.transfer(address(this).balance);
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *data* field? I don't see a *data* field in the contract.

Comment: there is one in the json file

Comment: How did you generate the json file? My guess is that there's a missing flag or the field was renamed or moved within the file. You have to provide more details. It doesn't seem to be related to the contract, but the tool used to generate the json file.

Comment: I think I was using truffle